# "comma" or "and" between section names?

Tags: commas, formal-language, academic-writing

"Comma" or "and"?

***Case 1:***

> In §2.1 **and** §2.2 we prove ...

or

> In §2.1, §2.2 we prove ...

***Case 2:***

> As mentioned in Section 2 (§2.1 **and** §2.2) ...

or

> As mentioned in Section 2 (§2.1, §2.2) ...

Comment: I can't think of any situation where you would use a comma rather than **and** between just two items. Where did you get that idea from?

Comment: @JavaLatte,  I am not an English native speaker (I saw only "and", but I was thinking maybe the "comma" is also ok).

Comment: Perhaps you are thinking of 2.1, 2.2 and 2.3 where the first comma is OK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replacing “and” with a comma is “Headlinese”, where normal rules of grammar are superseded by the need for brevity. You should not do this in prose like your case 1.

However, I do like parenthetical comments or references to be brief, so I might use this technique in your case 2.